# Wcf resful service Method = "DELETE"

Tags: rest, wcf

The contract of my method is like this:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(
        Method = "DELETE", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "/myMethod({myParametar})", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare
                )]
    void myMethod(string myParametar);
```

And I call it like this:

http://localhost:1234/MyService.svc/jsonPS/myMethod(1)

and it says Method not allowed.
Why?

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling it using a web browser, it is issuing a `GET`.  Instead, you can test this using a client like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/), which will let you set the method to `DELETE`.

Also, I don't believe you can pass a parameter in parentheses as you have it declared (I could be wrong about this, but I don't recall ever seeing it).  Instead, you can specify the segment to be the parameter:

`UriTemplate = "/{myParameter}"`

or pass it on the query string:

`UriTemplate = "?myMethod={myParameter}"`